# Should I add library to my project requirements if this library is already required by other requirement?

Tags: dependency-management

Let's say I have some library "foo" and I have it listed as dependency of my project. For example in Python I have requirements file saying

```
foo==1.0
```

foo library needs "bar" library and it lists it as dependency. At one point I realize "bar" can be useful for my project too, and I have an idea of calling some function of "bar" directly. So I add

```
import bar
```

somewhere in my project code.

Should I now add bar library to my project dependencies? If I don't add it my build system will not complain about missing bar because bar is already required and installed by foo. What is recommended practice in case like this?

Comment: The day you no longer need `foo`, you'll be thankful you added `bar` to your list of dependencies. After all, it _is_ a dependency.

Comment: The day you call a function from bar is the day you add it to your list of dependencies. If you don't need it yet, don't import it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't hurt.

- It's explicit. Relying on someone else's dependencies looks a bit like cheating. it works, but it's like you were abusing the dependency tree feature.
- You may remove `foo` one day, and be very surprised that your app stopped working for a cryptic dependency reason.
- You may upgrade `foo`, and the newer version could be using a new version of `bar`. it appears that the developers of `foo` did a great job of migrating their code, but yours still uses the old version of `bar`. Actually, the new `foo` may even not use `bar` at all.
- `foo` may use an old version of `bar` which doesn't have the features you need, so you may be interested in having a dependency to the newer version.

Note that if you actually need to run two different versions of the same package within the same app, [you may be in trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6572017/240613).